# calculate gradient output for Theta update rule

Tags: java, gradient-descent

As this uses a sigmoid function instead of a zero/one activation function I guess this is the right way to calculate gradient descent, is that right?

```
  static double calculateOutput( int theta, double weights[], double[][] feature_matrix, int file_index, int globo_dict_size )
  {
     //double sum = x * weights[0] + y * weights[1] + z * weights[2] + weights[3];
     double sum = 0.0;

     for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
     {
         sum += ( weights[i] * feature_matrix[file_index][i] );
     }
     //bias
     sum += weights[ globo_dict_size ];

     return sigmoid(sum);
  }

  private static double sigmoid(double x)
  {
      return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
  }
```

This following code where I'm trying up update my Θ values, (equivalent to weights in perceptron, isn't it?), I was given this formula `LEARNING_RATE * localError * feature_matrix__train[p][i] * output_gradient[i]` for that purpose in my [**related question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913062/modify-perceptron-to-become-gradient-descent). I commented out the weight update from my perceptron.

Is this new update rule the correct approach?

What is meant by output_gradient? Is that equivalent to the sum I calculate in my `calculateOutput` method?

```
      //LEARNING WEIGHTS
      double localError, globalError;
      int p, iteration, output;

      iteration = 0;
      do 
      {
          iteration++;
          globalError = 0;
          //loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
          for (p = 0; p < number_of_files__train; p++) 
          {
              // calculate predicted class
              output = calculateOutput( theta, weights, feature_matrix__train, p, globo_dict_size );
              // difference between predicted and actual class values
              localError = outputs__train[p] - output;
              //update weights and bias
              for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
              {
                  //weights[i] += ( LEARNING_RATE * localError * feature_matrix__train[p][i] );

                  weights[i] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * feature_matrix__train[p][i] * output_gradient[i]

              }
              weights[ globo_dict_size ] += ( LEARNING_RATE * localError );

              //summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
              globalError += (localError*localError);
          }

          /* Root Mean Squared Error */
          if (iteration < 10) 
              System.out.println("Iteration 0" + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( globalError/number_of_files__train ) );
          else
              System.out.println("Iteration " + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( globalError/number_of_files__train ) );
          //System.out.println( Arrays.toString( weights ) );
      } 
      while(globalError != 0 && iteration<=MAX_ITER);
```

---

**UPDATE**
Now I've updated things, looks more like this:

```
  double loss, cost, hypothesis, gradient;
  int p, iteration;

  iteration = 0;
  do 
  {
    iteration++;
    cost = 0.0;
    loss = 0.0;

    //loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
    for (p = 0; p < number_of_files__train; p++) 
    {

      // 1. Calculate the hypothesis h = X * theta
      hypothesis = calculateHypothesis( theta, feature_matrix__train, p, globo_dict_size );

      // 2. Calculate the loss = h - y and maybe the squared cost (loss^2)/2m
      loss = hypothesis - outputs__train[p];

      // 3. Calculate the gradient = X' * loss / m
      gradient = calculateGradent( theta, feature_matrix__train, p, globo_dict_size, loss );

      // 4. Update the parameters theta = theta - alpha * gradient
      for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
      {
          theta[i] = theta[i] - (LEARNING_RATE * gradient);
      }

    }

    //summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
    cost += (loss*loss);


  /* Root Mean Squared Error */
  if (iteration < 10) 
      System.out.println("Iteration 0" + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( cost/number_of_files__train ) );
  else
      System.out.println("Iteration " + iteration + " : RMSE = " + Math.sqrt( cost/number_of_files__train ) );
  //System.out.println( Arrays.toString( weights ) );

  } 
  while(cost != 0 && iteration<=MAX_ITER);


}

static double calculateHypothesis( double theta[], double[][] feature_matrix, int file_index, int globo_dict_size )
{
    double hypothesis = 0.0;

     for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
     {
         hypothesis += ( theta[i] * feature_matrix[file_index][i] );
     }
     //bias
     hypothesis += theta[ globo_dict_size ];

     return hypothesis;
}

static double calculateGradent( double theta[], double[][] feature_matrix, int file_index, int globo_dict_size, double loss )
{
    double gradient = 0.0;

     for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
     {
         gradient += ( feature_matrix[file_index][i] * loss);
     }

     return gradient;
}

public static double hingeLoss()
{
    // l(y, f(x)) = max(0, 1 − y · f(x))

    return HINGE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `calculateOutput` method looks correct. Your next piece of code I don't really think so:

```
weights[i] += LEARNING_RATE * localError * feature_matrix__train[p][i] * output_gradient[i]
```

Look at the image you posted in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916191/gradient-descent-as-applied-to-feature-vector-bag-of-words-classification-task/28920368#28920368):

[image: Update rules for Theta]

Let's try to identify each part of these rules in your code.

1. `Theta0 and`Theta1: looks like `weights[i]` in your code; I hope `globo_dict_size = 2`;
2. `alpha`: seems to be your `LEARNING_RATE`;
3. `1 / m`: I can't find this anywhere in your update rule. `m` is the number of training instances in Andrew Ng's videos. In your case, it should be `1 / number_of_files__train` I think; It's not very important though, things should work well even without it.
4. The sum: you do this with the `calculateOutput` function, whose result you make use of in the `localError` variable, which you multiply by `feature_matrix__train[p][i]` (equivalent to `x(i)` in Andrew Ng's notation).

   **This part is your partial derivative, and part of the gradient!**

   Why? Because the partial derivative of `[h_theta(x(i)) - y(i)]^2` with respect to `Theta0` is equal to:

   ```
   2*[h_theta(x(i)) - y(i)] * derivative[h_theta(x(i)) - y(i)]
   derivative[h_theta(x(i)) - y(i)] =
   derivative[Theta0 * x(i, 1) + Theta1*x(i, 2) - y(i)] =
   x(i, 1)
   ```

   Of course, you should derive the entire sum. This is also why Andrew Ng used `1 / (2m)` for the cost function, so the `2` would cancel out with the `2` we get from derivation.

   Remember that `x(i, 1)`, or just `x(1)` should consist of all ones. In your code, you should make sure that:

   ```
   feature_matrix__train[p][0] == 1
   ```
5. That's it! I don't know what `output_gradient[i]` is supposed to be in your code, you don't define it anywhere.

I suggest you take a look at [this tutorial](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf) to get a better understanding of the algorithm you have used. Since you use the sigmoid function, it seems like you want to do classification, but then you should use a different cost function. That document deals with logistic regression as well.

Comment: my comprehension of your explaination completely breaks down when you say that `feature_matrix__train[p][i] == 1`, what does that mean?!? of course it doesn't == 1, it's the number of times the word to which it corresponds has appeared in the global dictionary! It could equal one, but it could also equal zero or five hundred!

Comment: @S.Matthew_English - my bad, I meant to write `0` instead of `i`. It should equal 1 for the first element only. Sorry, I corrected it now.

Comment: is that the same as the bias term? why do I have to put it at the beginning, can it go at the end?

Comment: @S.Matthew_English - yes, it's the bias term. It's usually put at the beginning because it makes vectorization easier that way, but you can put it anywhere in your case.